# Use git to track your Cordova App for various devices

Tags: git, cordova, git-subtree

I have a Cordova App which I use for practically 4 "devices":

1. The test environment
2. Android build
3. iOS build (on a different machine)
4. Web- build

**Practically, I want to clean up the code and track the main project from a single source, and track only adaptions of the other code- bits**

Currently I use git to track changes on the test environment, then pull in the changes via rsync (from a remote server - which practically acts as a backup, too). I have some files which are different (e.g. cordova.js and another .js file which is contains some different routines for mobile/test/webapp).
So here I go:

1. ~/Project/< myhtmlfiles >
2. /otherpath/ProjectAndroid/platforms/android/assets/www/< myhtmlfiles > (e.g. with Cordova 3.3)
3. me@othermachine:/ProjectiOS/platforms/ios/assets/www/< myhtmlfiles > (e.g. with Cordova 3.0)
4. /otherpath/ProjectWeb/< myhtmlfiles >

So I want the common < myhtmlfiles > to be pulled in from 1., but also have 2-3 files which I would need to handle separately (e.g. ./cordova.js and ./scripts/global.js) - same name, different content each time - and obviously not being overridden each time I pull changes.

I have seen a few hints with sub-trees, but I'm not really getting my head around it what the best approach is, **especially** when having **certain files** which are "within" the main project, **but with different content** to each sub- or sideproject.

I hope solving this can help others others too to organize their code...